# FirebaseStorage Error react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage, create-react-app, expo

I am writing a function to upload a file to firebaseStorage using the firebase node sdk. My code is exaclty the example given

```
var message = 'data:text/plain;base64,5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
ref.putString(message, 'data_url').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```

the interesting part is than when I test this code on my android emulator, it works fine. But when i try it out on my physical device it throws this error:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 10):
FirebaseStorageError {
  "code_": "storage/retry-limit-exceeded",
  "message_": "Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again.",
  "name_": "FirebaseError",
  "serverResponse_": null,
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error uploading a blob. If anyone figures this out please update